# ¿Cómo interactuar con componentes del sistema operativo?

Tags: java, windows10

Quisiera saber cómo obtener datos de componentes del sistema operativo (Windows 10), por ejemplo el reproductor de música:

[image: Windows 10 Reproductor]

Obtener datos como el título de lo que está sonando y el autor. Y así poder almacenarlos en una variable para luego ser usado.

Comment: Para hacer lo que quieres creo que lo mejor es que uses el Framework .NET

Comment: @E.Betanzos en ese caso como se manejan ese tipo de datos?. Si sabes de algun enlace de documentacion fuese muy bueno, probaria con .NET

Comment: El reproductor de música no es un componente del sistema operativo. Es un programa que corre en Windows, como cualquier otro. Que lee ficheros y los reproduce. No se cómo pretendes acceder a sus propios datos si el propio programa no tiene una interfaz para permitir hacerlo. Ni en Java, ni en .NET ni en nada.

Comment: @SuperG280 si te fijas en la pregunta del OP verás como el control de volumen de Windwos es capaz de detectar la fuente del audio que se está reproduciendo y por ende puede interactuar con dicha fuente (por ejemplo mostrar el título de la canción, etc). Este tipo de interacción con Windows el framework .NET es quién mejor la soporta.

Comment: @QwertyUiop no tengo buena documentación de .NET pero de seguro que si haces una búsqueda en Google encontrará muchísima info.